# Bash script fails during Dockerfile build process

Tags: linux, bash, shell, docker, sh

I have a Dockerfile which looks like this:

```
FROM node:14.0.0 as dev-stage
WORKDIR /app
ENV NODE_ENV=development
COPY package.json ./
RUN yarn install

FROM node:14.0.0 as build-stage
WORKDIR /app
ENV NODE_ENV=production
COPY --from=dev-stage /app/node_modules node_modules
COPY . .
RUN yarn run build

FROM abiosoft/caddy:1.0.3
COPY Caddyfile /etc/Caddyfile

COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist /usr/share/caddy/html

WORKDIR /usr/share/caddy/html
COPY ./env.sh .
COPY .env .
RUN chmod +x env.sh && /usr/share/caddy/html/env.sh
```

and a `env.sh` script which looks like this:

```
# Recreate config file
rm -rf ./config.js
touch ./config.js

# Add assignment 
echo "window._env_ = {" >> ./config.js

# Read each line in .env file
# Each line represents key=value pairs
while read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]];
do
  # Split env variables by character `=`
  if printf '%s\n' "$line" | grep -q -e '='; then
    varname=$(printf '%s\n' "$line" | sed -e 's/=.*//')
    varvalue=$(printf '%s\n' "$line" | sed -e 's/^[^=]*=//')
  fi

  # Read value of current variable if exists as Environment variable
  value=$(printf '%s\n' "${!varname}")
  # Otherwise use value from .env file
  [[ -z $value ]] && value=${varvalue}

  # Append configuration property to JS file
  echo "  $varname: \"$value\"," >> ./config.js
done < .env

echo "}" >> ./config.js
```

When I try to build it, I get this error message

```
Step 18/18 : RUN chmod +x env.sh && /usr/share/caddy/html/env.sh
 ---> Running in 9e928ef2d9fd
/usr/share/caddy/html/env.sh: line 27: syntax error: bad substitution
/usr/share/caddy/html/env.sh: line 27: syntax error: bad substitution
/usr/share/caddy/html/env.sh: line 27: syntax error: bad substitution
/usr/share/caddy/html/env.sh: line 27: syntax error: bad substitution
/usr/share/caddy/html/env.sh: line 27: syntax error: bad substitution
/usr/share/caddy/html/env.sh: line 27: syntax error: bad substitution
/usr/share/caddy/html/env.sh: line 27: syntax error: bad substitution
```

Running the script locally works just fine, exactly how I intended, just not in the Docker build process.  What am I missing here.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your script is written for `bash`, but you're running it with `/bin/sh`, which in the `node:14.0.0` image is *not* a link to `bash`. Instead, it's a traditional POSIX shell.

The `${!varname}` syntax in particular is a bash-ism:

```
  value=$(printf '%s\n' "${!varname}")
```

The easiest way to resolve this is to start your script with:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Or just change your final `RUN` line to look like this:

```
RUN bash /usr/share/caddy/html/env.sh
```

---

Here's my test.  If I start with an `env.sh` that looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

foo=1
varname=foo
echo "foo is ${!varname}"
```

And this `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:14.0.0

COPY env.sh /tmp/env.sh
RUN chmod +x /tmp/env.sh; /tmp/env.sh
```

It fails as expected with:

```
/tmp/env.sh: 5: /tmp/env.sh: Bad substitution
```

But if I modify the `Dockerfile` to look like this:

```
FROM node:14.0.0

COPY env.sh /tmp/env.sh
RUN bash /tmp/env.sh
```

It works as desired.

Comment: I've tried both of those and I'm getting  `/bin/sh: bash: not found; The command '/bin/sh -c bash /usr/share/caddy/html/env.sh' returned a non-zero code: 127`.  I'm assuming I need to chose an image which has bash or rewrite the script to work with sh

Comment: The `node:14.0.0` image appears to have bash installed. I've updated my answer with the test I ran locally.